# An Update statement in a loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2012

I have this table in a gridview.

```
ID     Question_No          Question             Survey_ID
-----------------------------------------------------------

 1         1            Whats you name?             44
 2         2            How Old Are you?            44
 3         3       Whats your favorite hobby        44
 4         4          What did you study?           44
```

I want to add a remove button to the page that works like this: When i delete one of these records, i want to update the question_no of all the questions automatically as long as the survey_ID is 44. For example, If i delete the 2nd question, it would become like this.

```
    ID     Question_No          Question             Survey_ID
-----------------------------------------------------------

     1         1            Whats you name?             44
     3         2       Whats your favorite hobby        44
     4         3          What did you study?           44
```

How do i do this? i figured it must be a loop, but i have no idea how to even approach it.

EDIT: This is my remove button code

```
protected void RemoveQuestionButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                DataRowView r;
                r = ((DataRowView)QuestionsGridView.GetRow(QuestionsGridView.FocusedRowIndex));
                Session["Question_ID"] = r[0];

                if (Session["Question_ID"] != null)
                {
                    SqlConnection connection = DatabaseConnection.GetSurveySystemConnection();
                    string delStatement1 = "DELETE FROM Questions WHERE ID =" + Session["Question_ID"];
                    string delStatement2 = "DELETE FROM Question_Options where Question_ID=" + Session["Question_ID"];
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(delStatement1, connection);
                    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(delStatement2, connection);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                    try
                    {
                        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        ConfirmLbl.ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("Green");
                        ConfirmLbl.Text = "Question & Options Deleted Successfully!";
                        QuestionsGridView.DataBind();

                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        ConfirmLbl.ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("red");
                        ConfirmLbl.Text = "This Question Has Options Linked to it...";
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        connection.Close();

                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                ConfirmLbl.ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("red");
                ConfirmLbl.Text = "You need to select a Question to edit...";
            }
        }
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Seems like nothing if he doesn't know how to even approach it.

Comment: Do you have any C# code that you have attempted to do on your own..? providing you a quick answer does not really help you to learn C# please take the time to google and or try coding yourself first..

Comment: Are you pulling this data from a database or some other source? If so, when you delete a question, are you deleting the question from the source?

Comment: yes, iam pulling it from an sqldatasource connected to sqlserver and yes, i delete it from the source, i'm editing my question now to provide you with what i have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with a single update statement.

```
delete from question
   where id = 2;

with new_order as (
   select row_number() over (partition by survey_id order by question_no) as new_question_no,
          question_no as old_question_no, 
          id
   from question
) 
update question 
  set question_no = nq.new_question_no
from new_order nq
where nq.id = question.id
  and survey_id = 44;

commit;
```

Here is an SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0a1e7/1

Answer (score 1):

All you need is a function that queries the db table and sets/binds the result set to your gridview. Then when you delete a question and remove it from the database, call that function and rebind your gridview to the new result set.

You can use [partition ROW_NUMBER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) in your sql query to make a sequential column of row numbers. You can take a look at some of the examples there to help you execute this.

Comment: Well, i thought of adding a select and update statement under the delete statements, and when i delete it would check the order numbers of the questions, and then set them again, but the problem is how can i update a column with the values : 1,2,3,4 etc, until the column ends?